# Showing continuously updating figures on a big screen

Tags: display

I'm planning to have a bunch of plots displayed on a separate screen (50 inches), with its own Windows laptop connected to it. The plots will be generated on our server.

I've never attempted something like this before, and have no idea where to start. We essentially want to have a bunch of plots (.png) displayed in a grid, say 9x9, and the plots on the display update when the file on the server changes (this file is created by a .py cronjob).

Any ideas on how this could be solved? Much appreciated

I'm literally drawing blanks

Comment: I would say that it depends on what language you wish to use, what you or your team is familiar with. I am used to Python so I know you can use opencv, pyqt or simply matplotlib libraries to display images ; and with a bit of tweaking you should be able to make them update when the files get changed.

Comment: Game libraries can also be used to manage windows, scenes, images, ... pyglet is an example in Python but I never used it so you would need to do some more digging to see if it's what you want.